# Finite union of intervals as finite union of disjoint intervals

Tags: real-analysis

From "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin:

> Let $R^{p}$ denote $p$-dimensional euclidean space. By an interval in
>   $R^{p}$ we mean the set of points $\vec{x} = (x_{1}, \ldots, x_{p})$
>   such that
>
> \begin{equation} \text{(10)} \quad a_{i} \leq x_{i} \leq b_{i} \quad
> > (i = 1, \ldots, p), \\ \end{equation}
>
> or the set of points which is characterized by (10) with any or all of
>   the $\leq$ signs replaced by <. The possibility that $a_{i} = b_{i}$
>   for any value of $i$ is not ruled out; in particular, the empty set is
>   included among the intervals.
>
> If $A$ is the union of a finite number of intervals, $A$ is said to be
>   an elementary set.
>
> We let $\mathcal{E}$ denote the family of all elementary subsets of
>   $R^{p}$.
>
> At this point, the following properties should be verified: ...
>
> (13) If $A \in \mathcal{E}$, then $A$ is the union of a finite number
>   of disjoint intervals.

I have a general outline of a proof, but I am having trouble translating it into more precise terms:

Let $A$ be the union of a finite number of intervals. Let $S_{i}$ be the ordered sequence of all the endpoints in $A$ for dimension $i$. Let $T_{i}$ be the set of pairs of adjacent elements of $S_{i}$. Define each interval in the set of intervals $I$ by taking the endpoints in dimension $i$ as the elements of $T_{i}$. Let $I'$ be the set of intervals in $I$ that have a nonempty intersection with $A$. Then $I'$ is a finite set of intervals and its union is $A$.

Is this the right idea? If so, how can I expand it to be more precise?

Comment: Your idea looks right for me.

Comment: I think it is better to define an interval in $I$ to be of the form $[a_1,b_1]\times \dots \times [a_p,b_p]$, where $a_i,b_i$ are adjacent in $S_i$. Then you can drop $T_i$ and the order on $S_i$

Comment: Why can I drop the order on $S_{i}$?

Comment: If you just want adjacent points in $S_i$, then it is no need to order $S_i$?